# Insert records in table using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2019

I need to copy all data in `MyDatabase` on `SERVER1` to `SERVER2`.

- `SERVER1` and `SERVER2` are in different domains.
- `SERVER1` can be reached from `SERVER2` using `SQL Authentication`.
- `SERVER1` and `SERVER2` are not linked.
- I only have `SELECT` rights on `Mydatabase` on `SERVER1`.
- Only tooling to be used is `PowerShell`

My idea was to write a powershell script that get the names of all tables in MyDatabase on SERVER1, create a `SELECT * FROM table` statement and execute those one by one.. Insert the returned records in a new table in `MyDatabase` on `SERVER2`.

I used that trick to write the data from a database to CSV files. However, now I want to write the data not to a file but to a table.

See the code below

```
    $server_src = "SERVER1" #$args[0]
    $database_src = "MyDatabase" #$args[1]
    $auth_src = "UID=MyUser;PWD=Mypassword" #$args[2]
    $server_dst = "SERVER2" #$args[3]
    $database_dst = "MyDatabase" #$args[4]
    $auth_dst = "UID=MyUser;PWD=Mypassword" #$args[5]
    
    # set source
    $connection_string_src = "Server = $server_src; Database = $database_src; $auth_src;"
    $connection_src = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connection_string_src
    # set destination
    $connection_string_dst = "Server = $server_dst; Database = $database_dst; $auth_dst;"
    $connection_dst = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connection_string_dst
    
    # sql to execute on source - get all tables in database $database_src
    $sql_src = "select distinct  
    '$database_src' as dbname
    ,s.name as schemaname
    ,t.name as tablename
    ,  'SELECT  * FROM ' + quotename('$database_src')+'.'+
        quotename(s.name)+'.'+
        quotename(t.name) 
    AS selectquery 
    ,UPPER(s.name+'.'+t.name) as [dst_name]
    from  $database_src.sys.schemas s  
    inner join $database_src.sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id"
    
    # actually open the connection and execute $sql_src
    $command_src = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $sql_src,$connection_src
    $connection_src.Open()
    $adapter_src = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command_src
    $dataset_src = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    [void] $adapter_src.Fill($dataset_src)
    $connection_src.Close()
    
    #loop through source query's and insert data in $records
    [array] $rows=($dataset_src.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows)
    $i=0
    foreach ($row in $rows)
    {
    $query =   $rows[$i].selectquery
    $dst_name = $rows[$i].dst_name
    $command_src = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $query,$connection_src
    $connection_src.Open()
    $adapter_src = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command_src
    $wanteddata_src = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    [void] $adapter_src.Fill($wanteddata_src)
    $connection_src.Close()
    
# I think I only need to alter the 2 lines below to write the data to a table called $dst_name in the database $database_dst on the server $server_dstinstead of a file. Any existing table on the destination should be destroyed.
    
    
    $outputfile = "C:\ExportedData\"+$def_filename+ ".csv"
    $records= ($wanteddata_src.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows) | export-csv -Path $outputfile -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
    
    
    $i++
    }
```

Comment: "Only tooling to be used is PowerShell", but you are actually using the .Net COM model for SqlClient, so that has to be present anyhow... so why not work with TSQL?

Comment: your conclusion is right. How would you do this using SSMS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a SQL-guy :/ Try adding SQL as a tag to expand the area of your question.

Comment: good suggestion